# Pandas as_matrix() to values keep column order

Tags: python, pandas

I currently use the .as_matrix() function in order to ensure that the numpy array keeps the correct column order; however this is due to be depreciated. How can I ensure the column order is maintained once the as_matrix function is depreciated by using the suggested .values function? Or is there another method?

Many thanks

Example with as_matrix

```
In: prices.pct_change()[1:].as_matrix(stocks)

Out: array([-0.00283364,  0.0012285 ,  0.0014199 ,  0.00142983, -0.0053432 ])
```

Example with Values

```
In: prices.pct_change()[1:].values

Out: array([ 0.00142983,  0.0014199 , -0.00283364, -0.0053432 ,  0.0012285 ])
```

Comment: How does accessing `values` disturb the order?

Comment: Can you please link the source of this info? I'm already hanging behind on versions due to `agg()` going :/

Comment: Just use `.values`, nothing to worry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you point out, `.as_matrix()` is deprecated.  (See below for comparison to `.values`.)

Regardless, seems like you can get the columns in respective order by using `.loc` first:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(444)

prices = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(200, 4), columns=list('abcd'))
columns = list('cad')
prices.pct_change().dropna().loc[:, columns].values
```

Here's the [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6d031f2b739ac1197cbb81b36cdea5f954d4e065/pandas/core/generic.py) for `.as_matrix()` versus `.values`.  You'll notice only a slight difference:

```
def as_matrix(self, columns=None):
    warnings.warn("Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. "
                      "Use .values instead.", FutureWarning, stacklevel=2)
    self._consolidate_inplace()
    return self._data.as_array(transpose=self._AXIS_REVERSED,
                               items=columns)

@property
def values(self):
    self._consolidate_inplace()
    return self._data.as_array(transpose=self._AXIS_REVERSED)
```

Hence if you really wanted to, you could just recreate `.as_matrix()` without the warning.  (But I would strongly prefer the first method; it's the public API; it doesn't make you deal with Pandas internal `Block` type yourself.)

```
chg = prices.pct_change().dropna()
val = chg._data.as_array(transpose=chg._AXIS_REVERSED, items=columns)
assert np.allclose(val, prices.pct_change().dropna().loc[:, columns].values)
```