# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn import ensemble

from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

from joblib import *

df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/Melbourne_housing_FULL.csv')

df.head(n=5)
del df['Address']
del df['Method']
del df['SellerG']
del df['Date']
del df['Postcode']
del df['Lattitude']
del df['Longtitude']
del df['Regionname']
del df['Propertycount']
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=True)
features_df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Suburb', 'CouncilArea', 'Type'])
X = features_df.as_matrix()
y = df['Price'].as_matrix()
```

Can anyone please help me I am facing a error as soon as I put  X = features_df.as_matrix()
    y = df['Price'].as_matrix() and I am learning Machine Learning with a book called Machine Learning with python by oliver... Any Help is highly appreciated Thankyou

Comment: try replacing it with `df['Price'].to_numpy()`

Comment: `df.as_matrix()` is deprecated, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309250/pandas-as-matrix-to-values-keep-column-order). TL;DR try using `df.values`.

Comment: Thankyou Worked...

Answer (score 74):

`df.as_matrix()` was deprecated after version 0.23.0.
Use `df.values` instead.

Follow [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) for additional information.

Comment: df.values --> no parantheses

Answer (score 17):

Dataframe depricated a lot of attributes such as `.ix`

Here you need this command:

```
y = df['Price'].values
```

Answer (score 16):

Replacing `.as_matrix()` with `.values()` also resulted in an error, but replacing it with `.to_numpy()` worked perfectly

> Convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array.
>
> New in version 0.24.0.

Comment: `.values()` wouldn't have worked because it is not a method. Use `.values` instead.

Answer (score 5):

As of Pandas 1.0 use `.to_numpy()` other ways are deprecated according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy)