# I am getting error('DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix') while running following code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

**Basic LSTM Model**
Import keras libraries

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display

from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

import lstm, time #helper libraries

import visualize as vs
import stock_data as sd
import LinearRegressionModel

stocks = pd.read_csv('E:/DBSOM DATA\FOM_Sem 2/Analyses of S&U Data/Project work/Stock-Price-Prediction-master/google_preprocessed.csv')
stocks_data = stocks.drop(['Item'], axis =1)

display(stocks_data.head())
```

**Spliting train and test data sets and Unroll train and test data for lstm model**

```
    X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = sd.train_test_split_lstm(stocks_data, 5)

    unroll_length = 50
    X_train = sd.unroll(X_train, unroll_length)
    X_test = sd.unroll(X_test, unroll_length)
    y_train = y_train[-X_train.shape[0]:]
    y_test = y_test[-X_test.shape[0]:]

    print("x_train", X_train.shape)
    print("y_train", y_train.shape)
    print("x_test", X_test.shape)
    print("y_test", y_test.shape)
```

**Function definition**

Split the data set into training and testing feature for Long Short Term Memory Model

```
def train_test_split_lstm(stocks, prediction_time=1, test_data_size=450, unroll_length=50):  

# training data
test_data_cut = test_data_size + unroll_length + 1
x_train = stocks[0:-prediction_time - test_data_cut].values
y_train = stocks[prediction_time:-test_data_cut]['Close'].values

# test data
x_test = stocks[0 - test_data_cut:-prediction_time].values
y_test = stocks[prediction_time - test_data_cut:]['Close'].values
return x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test
```

Use different windows for testing and training to stop from leak of information in the data

```
def unroll(data, sequence_length=24):
result = []
for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
    result.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])
return np.asarray(result)
```

**Error**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-59aa6ad29ad5> in <module>
----> 1 X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = sd.train_test_split_lstm(stocks_data, 5)
  2 
  3 unroll_length = 50
  4 X_train = sd.unroll(X_train, unroll_length)
  5 X_test = sd.unroll(X_test, unroll_length)

~\Stock Price Prediction\stock_data.py in train_test_split_lstm(stocks, prediction_time, test_data_size, unroll_length)
 77     test_data_cut = test_data_size + unroll_length + 1
 78 
 ---> 79     x_train = stocks[0:-prediction_time - test_data_cut].to_numpy()
 80     y_train = stocks[prediction_time:-test_data_cut]['Close'].to_numpy()
 81 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
5128             if 
self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
5129                 return self[name]
-> 5130             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
5131 
5132     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'
```

Comment: What is `sd`? Did you write these functions yourself (if yes, please include them in your question) or is this a library (if yes, please provide a link/full name for it)?

Comment: sd is stock_data.

Comment: Please include the implementations for `train_test_split_lstm` and `unroll`, since `sd` is *custom* code. Without these, we will not be able to help.

Comment: After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102281/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-as-matrix) I would suggest to update everything and then retry

Comment: I have added function definition

Comment: I have replaced .as_matrix() with .values, but still I am getting error

Answer (score 0):

I have wrongly import this sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler. After removing this line of code, everything runs smooth